# How to update a table from a trigger, when column name is dynamic?

Tags: mysql, sql

Schema and data for test database - https://gist.github.com/koceg/435c0d2b1246a69d048f

My goal is to update **boards** table, when somebody inserts a new row in the **objects_properties** table. The name of the column to update is dynamic - it depends on a *property_id* from **objects_properties**.

So far I've created a trigger and a stored procedure, but I'm getting this error:

> Dynamic sql is not allowed in stored function or trigger.

Am I doing something wrong or is mysql not allowing to call a stored procedure with a prepared statement inside a trigger? If so, how can I do what I want?

I have an idea, but it's ugly even in a pseudocode. Real SQL will be even worse, because there will be a few dozens codes:

```
SWITCH (property_code)
    CASE 'name'
        INSERT INTO boards (id, name) VALUES (@object_id, @value) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = @value;

    CASE 'address'
        INSERT INTO boards (id, address) VALUES (@object_id, @value) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE address = @value;

    CASE 'district'
        INSERT INTO boards (id, district) VALUES (@object_id, @value) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE district = @value;
```

P.S. I can't move this logic to my application, because this database is used by several applications.

Comment: It is a badly designed schema, but nothing I can do about it...

Comment: According to the MySQL documentation: [D.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html): "SQL prepared statements ([PREPARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/prepare.html), [EXECUTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/execute.html), [DEALLOCATE PREPARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/deallocate-prepare.html)) can be used in stored procedures, but not stored functions or triggers. Thus, stored functions and triggers cannot use dynamic SQL (where you construct statements as strings and then execute them). ".

Comment: Some options: Don't use Triggers to use Prepared Statements, or use Triggers without using Prepared Statements.

Comment: by looking at your schema, can only mention "circular reference". why would you want to have same data in two places? i guess your [objects_properties] table is normalized according to your requirements. The [boards] table is absolutely unnecessary(IMHO). are you trying to track the changes?

Comment: @krishKM, no I am denormalizing data to improve performance.I'm interested in only one type of objects an in only limited set of properties, but there is dozens of object types and each of them has hundreds of properties, so objects_properties is quite big. Plus it serves as a log table at the same time, so all previous values are stored there as well.

Comment: @wchiquito, yes, I've read the docs. And I'm using prepared statements in a stored procedure, which is OK, but I'm using that procedure inside a trigger. My code does not work, and I'm trying to understand is this a mysql limitation in action or my code is broken somewhere else.

Comment: @koceg "denormalizing" won't improve. what is your end goal? a list of bords with (name: address: district) and only the last entry?
instead of [boards] table you can create a view to produce this list

Comment: @krishKM but view is just a template for a complex queries, how is it faster then aggregated table? My goal is to see all active boards with all current properties. I'm using it a lot in my application and the query time is crucial. Now it takes about 10 seconds.

Comment: @koceg what is your current query that takes 10 seconds? can you produce that?

Comment: The stored procedure work correctly if called from outside of the trigger, the problem is that the context of execution of the stored procedure is the trigger, so the cause of the failure.

Comment: @krishKM, i actualy have another table and trigger - https://gist.github.com/koceg/5681b889249d730ea319
select * from that table takes 10 seconds. It currently has 274611 rows. objects_properties table has 2325412 rows and grows every day.

Comment: @wchiquito, thanks. So, i guess, my only option is to use a bunch of IF statements in the procedure.

Comment: @koceg can you build your schema http://sqlfiddle.com/ so its easier to test and explain.

Comment: @krishKM, thanks for your time, but this topic is well beyond the scope of my question.

Comment: @koceg: i would simply create a view with correct where condition. or would have altered the [boards] table like object_id, property_id, value. then you can use your objects_properties after insert event to either insert or update the columns in [bords] table.
after insert > insert into boards(id, property_id, value) values (new.object_id, new.property_id, new.value) on duplicate key update valuefield.

PS: you should consider schema level character encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Current MySQL (5.7) Manual section D.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs states that

1. SQL prepared statements (PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE PREPARE) can be used in stored procedures, but not stored functions or triggers. Thus, stored functions and triggers cannot use dynamic SQL (where you construct statements as strings and then execute them).
2. Generally, statements not permitted in SQL prepared statements are also not permitted in stored programs. For a list of statements supported as prepared statements .
3. Because local variables are in scope only during stored program execution, references to them are not permitted in prepared statements created within a stored program. Prepared statement scope is the current session, not the stored program, so the statement could be executed after the program ends, at which point the variables would no longer be in scope.
   So you can see that it's not permitted.

Regards.